# Java - throws not working for a subtype of an exception that is handled

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, handle, throws

Take this as example:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void test() throws SSLHandshakeException {
        throw new SSLHandshakeException("I'm a SSL Exception");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SSLHandshakeException {
        try {
            test ();        
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception");
        }       
    }
}
```

So, I have my test method in which I'm just throwing an `SSLHandshakeException` which is a subtype of `IOException`.

The output for this is "I`m handling IO exception".

Why does this happen? I expected that my method will throw the `SSLHandshakeException`. Is there a rule that `catch` is more important than `throws`?

I just want to avoid using

```
try {
   test ();     
} catch (SSLHandshakeException se) { 
   throw se; 
} catch (IOException ioe) {
   System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception");
}
```

Because I consider it less readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a rule that catch is more important than throws?

They are two completely different things. The `throws` keyword is part of the *method signature* and is saying 'This method *can* throw this exception, so every caller should handle that explicitly.'
Wether or not the method actually throws that exception is irrelevant here.

As for the `catch` statement. SSLHandshakeException *is an* IOException, and so it is caught as expected.

To get the behaviour you intent you can write:

```
    try {
        test ();
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException sslExc) {
        throw sslExc;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception that is not an SSLHandshakeException");
    }
```

---

Edit: You say you find this less readable. But honestly this is just the best way. If it would behave the way you proposed than you would never be able to catch an SSLHandshakeException in a method that might also throw it? What if you want to catch it in certain conditions but throw it in others? It would just be too limiting and unintuitive.

An alternative is like so; but in my opinion this is even less readable:

```
    try {
        test ();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        if(ioe instanceof SSLHandshakeException)
            throw ioe;
        System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception that is not an SSLHandshakeException");
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I get it now. The thing is I need my main method (in this case) to know how to handle IOExceptions other than SSLHandshakeException and pass the responsability for this to other calling methods.

Comment: I edited based on your edit to the question.  It would be ideal if the exceptions you need to catch are *other* subclasses of IOException. Then you can just catch those and the ssl exceptions will pass through. Otherwise this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you printed your custom string instead of message of exception. Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SSLHandshakeException {
    try {
        test ();        
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception");
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SSLHandshakeException` is a subclass of `javax.net.ssl.SSLException` wich is a subclass of `java.io.IOException`.

So this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SSLHandshakeException {
     try {
          test ();        
         } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("I`m handling IO exception");
        }       
}
```

will catch and IOException, and thus print the message "I`m handling IO exception".